# Angular ng-if expression on html view

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking to display a date value in my html (with a pipe expression), but only if that date exists.
If that field comes back as null, then I'm replacing it with `N/A` in my controller js code.

I think this should be simple, but I'm having a some trouble getting it to work.

This currently displays the date, or just blank if date is null.

```html
<div>
   <label> 
   {{ctrl.data.myDate | stringToDate:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
   </label>
</div>
```

I'm trying :

```html
<div>
       <label> 
       <span ng-if="ctrl.data.myDate!='N/A'">
          {{ctrl.data.myDate | stringToDate:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
       </span>
       </label>
       
       <label> 
       <span ng-if="ctrl.data.myDate=='N/A'">
          N/A
       </span>
       </label>
       
</div>
```

However, it's displaying `null` when the date is `N/A`.

This works, but without the pipe expression - however, I NEED to pipe the date string properly:

```
 <span>{{vm.data.myDate==='N/A' ? "N/A" : vm.data.myDate }}</span>
```

**UPDATE**

I'm trying a different approach where I can use the Angular `$filter` provider. So if `myDate` is NOT NULL, I can format the date in my js controller :

```
  vm.data.myDate = $filter('date')(new Date(data[0].closeDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: Pipe is only 1 bar (`|`). Two bars (`||`) is the OR operator

Comment: ternary expression, perhaps, in embedded in the html ?

Comment: Is `ctrl.data.myDate` equal to the string "N/A" **before** it runs through the date filter?

Comment: @mhodges - yes it is equal to N/A prior to the date filter. In my controller js code, I check for `null` in `.myDate`. If `null` then I replace with `N/A`. Please see my updated post with ternary expression.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior. Can you create a demo that replicates the problem you are experiencing? http://jsbin.com/junamahosu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Just for giggles, could you put `{{ctrl.data.myDate}}` right above the first `<label>` and tell me what it displays? You may be running into scoping or digest cycle issues that are the result of complexities not posted in your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138254/discussion-between-mhodges-and-bob-mazzo).

Comment: it just displays the raw date value `3/13/2017 12:00:00 AM`

Answer (score 1):

```
 <span>
{{ (vm.data.myDate==='N/A' || !vm.data.myDate) ? "N/A" : (vm.data.myDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd') }}
</span>
```

Comment: That displays nothing at all. My date is just blank now. As I mention in my OP, this works but only if I remove the pipe (which is not what I want to do) - `<span>{{vm.data.myDate==='N/A' ? "N/A" : vm.data.myDate }}</span>`

Comment: @bob.mazzo I didn't removed pipe `|`

Comment: yes, thank you. I'm just saying that your answer just displays a blank value. I have also tried the same thing, embedding the date and pipe within parenths (but it doesn't work).

Comment: I think filtering the date in javascript is the best approach, and remove the pipe in the html. I just need to figure that out in js.

Comment: did u checked `vm.data.myDate` what it displying?

Answer (score 1):

Having view value and model value in one variable is wrong approach. You should follow one of:

Store only model value, so you have date in js that can be null, and in html:

```
{{ctrl.data.myDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' || 'N/A'}}
```

Or you store also view value, then you should parse it in controller:

```
     ctrl.data.myDateText = $filter('date')(ctrl.data.myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); || 'N/A'
in html: {{ctrl.data.myDateText}}
```

Comment: @Peter - your second approach was also my second approach (see my UPDATE note in my OP). Thank you.